# AngularJS: loading async translations issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-scope, translation

I am building a Website with AngularJS. I ran into problems with translations, got a hacky more or less working solution to it but i am thinking that it can be done a lot better.

I have a main controller which loads translations from database.

```
$http.get($rootScope.ApiUrl + '/?a=sprache&lang=' + $rootScope.lang).success(function (data) {
        $scope.spr = data;
        $rootScope.translations = data;
        $rootScope.updateTranslations();
    });
```

data is an array formatted like this:

```
{key: "translation",…}
```

Further on I have a controller for each state. I hoped it could do something like this:

```
app.controller('InventoryCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$http',
'$location',
'$state',
'$stateParams',
'$rootScope',
'$uibModalStack',
function ($scope, $http, $location, $state, $stateParams, $rootScope, $uibModalStack) {
    $scope.title = $rootscope.translations.myTranslatedTitleForThisState
]);
```

Obviously this does not work as the get-request is not finished before this Code gets called and therefore $rootscope.translations variable is not set.

Instead I wrote the following. The updateTranslations() function is called from the loadTransition() function in MainController (above) after successfully finishing the get-request.

```
app.controller('InventoryCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$http',
'$location',
'$state',
'$stateParams',
'$rootScope',
'$uibModalStack',
function ($scope, $http, $location, $state, $stateParams, $rootScope, $uibModalStack) {
    $rootScope.updateTranslations = function() {
        $rootScope.setMetaTags($rootScope.translations.inventory_title, $rootScope.translations.inventory_description);
        $rootScope.updateTranslations();
    }
    }
]);
```

I am pretty sure this can be done a lot better. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is not a direct answer to your problem, but a possible new approach...

We have been using `ui-router` quite alot in recent Angular projects.
`ui-router` is ideal for defining routes within the application. More about that subject [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

A nice feature is the state `resolvement`. Meaning that the state will only resolve when the resolvement promise is resolved.

**By example**

```
angular.module('testApp').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        resolve: {
            labels: function(labelService) {
                return labelService.loadLabels();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In the above example, the state `/` will resolve after the `$http.get` promise behind the `loadService.loadLabels()` is resolved. Meaning the template will be loaded, after all the resolvements are resolved.

**In this case, your view will be loaded - after that all your labels are loaded and accessible by the controller (later the view).**

A nice thing is that `nested state definitions` are perfectly possible.
Meaning, that you could have 1 root state, and many child state of the root state.